# Does word TA comes from historically, or a psychically to many languages on earth?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, psycholinguistics

Does word TA comes from historically, or a psychically to many languages on earth?

- Ta, sumerian -root
- Ta, english -thank
- Ta, mongolian -grateful and respectful calling of "you"
  etc

Comment: An obvious answer (I hesitate to make it an answer since it's *too* obvious): Such simple words that are monosyllabic, containing a widespread consonant and maybe the most widespread vowel, exist maybe in **every** language, although they have different meanings. Also, Ta in English [seems to be](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TA) either a Danish loanword or an abbreviation of *"thanks again"*.

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely that a language will contain a word pronounced [ta] than that it will contain a word pronounced [sq'əčqs]. You can add to your list Chinese (3rd person pronoun), Norwegian ("take"), French "your (fem)", Swahili ("lamp"), Vietnamese ("it is"), Yoruba ("sold"). It is not a word of Shona or North Saami, because of minimum-size restrictions against CV words. It also isn't a word of most dialects of English (this is the first I've heard of its putative existence in English -- must be a British thing), but that's kind of an accidental gap (it depends on how you analyze the vowel of *law, pa, maw, bra*).

The sequence [ta] is the least-dispreferred across languages in terms of syllable structure and phoneme makeup, suffering only from extreme shortness, but minimum size is not a widely-enforced desideratum of word structure. So the chances are good that a given language will have [ta] as a word.